# Uncaught Type error in JavaScript during retrieving value from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, console

While attempting to retrieve whether a steam game is multiplayer or not using the Steam API, we ran into some confusing issues.

```
<script>
    var key = atob("MjEyNzlCNzdFNjFCOTI3MEQ1MDVEODEyNDYzRDFDOTA=");
    var app = {};

    function getGameName(AppID) {
        var gameURL = 'http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=' + AppID;
        var yql = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from json where url="' + gameURL + '"') + '&format=json&callback=?';
        $.getJSON(yql, function(data) {
            var _x1 = String(AppID);
            _x1 = _x1.substring(1);
            _x1 = "_" + _x1;
            if (data.query.results[_x1].data.catergories[0].id == '1') {
                app.gameName[AppID] = data.query.results[_x1].data.name;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

To run the code run in console getGameName(40).  This should return the name of the game, as it is multiplayer, however is comes up with an uncaught type error.
This is very confusing when line 13 (app.gameName[AppID]...) works, yet line 12 (if (...) does not work.

I'm just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advanced.

As requested, the exact error message is "Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

And the JSON that should be returned can be found [here](http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=40) although, since is has gone through the yahoo API it has some padding.

Comment: what error, and post `data` content as well.

Comment: added as requested by Mritunjay

Comment: You have a typo: `catergories` should be `categories`